# How to stop executing a group of bash instructions without stopping script?

Tags: bash

I want to divide bash instructions in one script into several groups, but not defining functions or separate scripts, so that if one of instructions in a group returns 0 the execution of the current group will stop, but execution of script continues (something like calling break in a loop, containing only one iteration).
As an analogy/example let's look at the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

{
  echo "first group"

  set -eo pipefail

  ls non_existing_directory
  echo "unreachable line"
}

{
  echo "second group"
}
```

Here `set -eo pipefail` will cause the whole script to stop, but I want it just to go to the second group instructions so that `echo "unreachable line"` will not be called

Comment: "...but not defining functions or separate scripts..." -- This would be the easiest way to do it though. Is the problem that you are not comfortable with bash functions? In that case it would *really* be much simpler to tell you how to do functions than to hack around the issue...

Comment: I just want to find out if there is some easy way to do it without functions, because there may be situation when I would group semantically not connected instructions into group. One can say than group them other way, but it is out of scope I guess

Comment: Run in a subshell `( ... )` ?

Comment: The semantic connection would be that you would want to not execute the following commands when an earlier one failed. If you can put them in a group (or subshell, as KamilCuk hinted at), you can put them in a function. There's no Wrath from Above coming for those who make a different decision on what belongs in a function and what in a subshell. ;-) Good to see you found your solution.

Comment: But there raises the problem of naming which can be avoided using subshell) And there is wrath from reviewer) of pull request))

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments using subshell `( ... )` did the job.
In example it is enough to use round brackets instead of curly brackets